# Activate the crystal from far

Tags: pc, dungeon-defenders

When I'm setting defenses at the other side of the map, is there a way to activate the crystal from far away, letting me kill enemies at the gate without running back-and-forth?

Comment: there is  a shortcut key for it, I don't remember what though (its been a while) I think it was 'e'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default shortcut key for this is <kbd>G</kbd>. Unfortunately, last time I knew, there wasn't a way to do this if you're playing with a controller on PC.

Comment: You can edit the configuration file at startup to have it on the controller - of course, there being a limited number of keys (on said controller) you may have to swap out a pre-set (and potentially more useful) button to do so.

Comment: I can do it with left stick click on controller with defaulted controls. But i use ps3 controller not an xbox360, so this maybe an issue.