# Is there a quick way to ready up, besides pressing the crystal

Tags: xbox-360, dungeon-defenders

After running all around the level, it is annoying to have to have each player run all the way back to the crystal.  Is there any quick "ready up" button?

I'm looking for a solution specific to the Xbox 360 version of the game - not using an Xbox 360 controller on the PC.

Comment: for some reason I thought this question has been asked before.  And the answer is yes, there is a shortcut key to ready up from anywhere

Comment: Now if I can only find out what that button is.  The game is a maze of menus and complexity.  I'm sure I'll grow to like it, but I currently spend half my time trying to figure out what button to press to do something I've forgotten how to do.

Comment: A bit of reading on trendy net says that the 360 bindings for auto-ready may not be actively working right now.

Comment: @yx: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57623/activate-the-crystal-from-far

Comment: The other question is for the PC version.  I tried to tag appropriately.  My interest is in the 360 version, which seems to have some differences.  I did not however know that the other question existed when I wrote this one - despite attempted searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, there is no quick way to ready up when playing on the Xbox 360.